# DCG(Definite clause grammar) in Prolog

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg, clause

I am trying to make a DCG in prolog so that I create a sentence based on some predicates. I have two pieces of information = properties of objects ("Charles is a man.") and relations between objects ("Charles is the father of William.")

The task is to create sentences like this

```
[charles,is,a,man]
[camilla,is,a,woman]
[camilla,is,the,wife,of,charles]
[charles,is,the,father,of,william]
[charles,is,the,husband,of,camilla]
```

I can create a simple DCG which can generate sentences but how I can implement the relations so that the subject(charles, camilla, charles) correspond to the predicate part (is a man, is a woman)?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how do you record the information that Charles is a male name and Camilla - a female name?

Comment: no really, more like when I have predicate man(charles) and father(charles,william) how to connect it with DCG.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine DCG rules with Prolog predicates as follows

```
rpn --> [RPN], {rpn(RPN)}.   /* relative pronoun */
rpn(that).
rpn(which).
rpn(who).
```

Example is taken from [J.R. Fisher's tutorial](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/7_2.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
zdanie --> person, " ", iss, " ", animal, ".".

 man --> "adam" or "john".
women --> "eve" or "travolta".
iss --> "is".
animal --> "dog" or "cat" or "bird".

sentence(Z) :-
   phrase(zdanie, [I|R]),
   code_type(I, to_lower(J)),
   atom_codes(Z, [0' , J|R]).
```

and so on.